# oncontextmenu="return false;" is not working in Opera?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

In my application having the requirement for disable the **right click** feature.

So I used the `oncontextmenu="return false;"` in the `body` tag.

It works fine in all browsers except **Opera**.

How can I disable the **right click** in **Opera**. ?

I have searched a lot in **Google** and can't find the solution there.Hope you people can help me for a good solution.

Comment: If sole purpose of disabling right click is that you want to hide the source from users than disabling right click would not work as there are many more ways to see the source of a page without a right click.

Comment: Thanks for reply...I am not trying to hide the source.I am doing chat application .So disabling the right click may avoid the users for un-expected issues.

Comment: using jQuery or plain javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].oncontextmenu = function(e){ e.preventDefault();}
```

Comment: Did you forget oncontextmenu?